# Hiding Duplicate column in rdlc

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

I have a duplicate that i want to do grouping on in visual studio 2010 rdlc report . I am new to grouping so i do not understand what i need to do .

Data is in following form

```
ServiceName   Date   Duration
Haven         4th    10
Haven         5th    15
SubTotal             25
Haven         4th    5
Haven         5th    10
SubTotal             15
GrandTotal           40
```

I want to show it as follow

```
ServiceName   Date   Duration
Haven         4th    10
              5th    15
SubTotal             25
Haven         4th    5
              5th    10
SubTotal             15
GrandTotal           40
```

I want to show in above format so that the duplicate servicename does not show with every row how shall i do the grouping here . Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by setting hideduplicate property of column servicename's value to DATASET name .

Answer (score 0):

U have to group on sevice name and in the sorting option u can do filter on the perticular Id